# Batch Command Question

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a batch file that designated as a folder name date of a previous day.How can I do?

Here is my batch file.

```
Set Tarih1=%date:.=%

d:\

cd \ Yeni Klasör

md %date:.=%

cd %date:.=%
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *possible*, but...

```
setlocal
set _today=%date:.=%
set _year=%_today:~0,4%
set _month=%_today:~4,2%
set _day=%_today:~6,2%

:: leap year?
set /a _yearm400=_year %% 400
set /a _yearm100=_year %% 100
set /a _yearm4=_year %% 4

if %_yearm400% equ 0 (set _leap=1) ^
else (if %_yearm100% equ 0 (set _leap=0) ^
else (if %_yearm4% equ 0 (set _leap=1) ^
else (set _leap=0)))

:: strip leading zeros
if %_month:~0,1% equ 0 set _month=%_month:~1%
if %_day:~0,1% equ 0 set _day=%_day:~1%

:: decrement day
set /a _day-=1

:: decrement month
if %_day% equ 0 (
    if %_month% equ 2 set _day=31
    if %_month% equ 3 set /a _day=28+_leap
    if %_month% equ 4 set _day=31
    if %_month% equ 5 set _day=30
    if %_month% equ 6 set _day=31
    if %_month% equ 7 set _day=30
    if %_month% equ 8 set _day=31
    if %_month% equ 9 set _day=31
    if %_month% equ 10 set _day=30
    if %_month% equ 11 set _day=31
    if %_month% equ 12 set _day=30
    if %_month% equ 1 set _day=31
    set /a _month-=1
)

:: decrement year
if %_month% equ 0 (
    set /a _year-=1
    set _month=12
)

:: format new date
if %_month% leq 9 set _month=0%_month%
if %_day% leq 9 set _day=0%_day%

echo %_year%%_month%%_day%
```

I suggest using a more capable programming languages - [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/dos-batch-programming-howto-get-and-display-yesterday-date), maybe Python or Perl.

---

PowerShell:

```
$yesterday=(get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -uformat %Y%m%d)
mkdir $yesterday
```

Python:

```
import os
import time
yesterday = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.localtime(time.time() - 86400))
os.mkdir(yesterday)
```

---

Also, when changing drives, you must use only the drive letter, without a path. `d:\` should be replaced with `d:` ... Or just use `cd /d D:\Yeni Klasör`.

Comment: I second POwerShell. It's available on Win 2003 and up, and runs on XP!

Comment: That batch file is crazy. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want (or can't) use Powershell, then you could do it calling a .vbs (VBScript file)

File CreateYesterdayFolder.vbs

```
' yyyymmdd.vbs - outputs the current date in the format yyyymmdd
Function Pad(Value, PadCharacter, Length)
    Pad = Right(String(Length,PadCharacter) & Value, Length)
End Function

Dim yesterday, folderName

yesterday = Date() - 1
folderName = Pad(Year(yesterday), "0", 4) & Pad(Month(yesterday), "0", 2) & Pad(Day(yesterday), "0", 2)

Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory
newDirPath = "c:\temp\" & folderName ' example 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = objFSO.CreateFolder(newDirPath)
```

In your batch file call it this way:

```
cscript CreateYesterdayFolder.vbs //NOLOGO
```

Comment: This just passes `cscript`, `Yesterday.vbs` and `//NOLOGO` as directory names to `mkdir`.

Comment: Oops, copied it from an old script I had in a different context. I've edited my answer.